# CONVERT CHAR(_) to BINARY(_) with specific encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server database with `COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS` and a column "x" `CHAR(4) COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS` and value `'0123'`, but when I do

```
CONVERT(BINARY(4), x)
```

I get `0x30313233` (presumably Latin1) rather than `0xF0F1F2F3` (EBCDIC).

I am executing the query in SQL Server Management Studio. What can I do to get the EBCDIC bytes of column "x" or any given string?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't (really) support EBCDIC encodings. The EBCDIC collations only dictate the order of code points in this case. It will "correctly" order `1` after `Z` based on code point order, for example, but it won't actually use the EBCDIC code points to encode the value (instead it uses Windows-1252). If you *really* wanted to you could write something that reverse engineers the code points based on the order, but I doubt this is worth it compared to doing the conversion client side.